# Getting duration of video taken by camera iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, video, camera

I am trying to get the duration of a video taken with the camera using UIImagePickerController on the iphone, has anyone found a solution to this?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now do this using AVFoundation you can make your movie into an AVAsset and then check the duration property

Answer (score 0):

*Oh, why, hello hopelessly obsolete answer. I'm afraid you're only left here as historical evidence that yes, before iOS 4 if you wanted to do anything remotely interesting on a recorded video (besides playing it) you had to implement the processing yourself.*

I don't know of any framework function to do so, so I'm afraid you'll have to parse the video container yourself (which by the way, is QuickTime/.mov) to extract this info. [It's not like it's not documented.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFPreface/qtffPreface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH202-TPXREF101) Luckily since the provider is known, you can trust all info to be truthful, which you can't assume of random videos found on the web.