# Get length of video after dismissing UIImagePicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdata

i want to get the length of a video that the user picks. Im using apples UIImagePicker,

here is my code so far:

```
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//assign the mediatype to a string 
//check the media type string so we can determine if its a video
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    webData = [[NSData alloc]init];
    webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    //[self post:webData];
    video = 1;
    upload.hidden = NO;

    ImagesCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1", nil];
[tableview reloadData];
```

Thanks :D

Comment: This link may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616146/getting-duration-of-video-taken-by-camera-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this

```
AVAsset *movie = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
CMTime movieLength = movie.duration;
```

Comment: Okay, and how would i go about NSLogging that? i NSLogged it as a %i and got 600 for a 19 second video. I also tried NSLogging it as a %@ and crashed. I want to be able to convert this to seconds. Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: Take a look here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001755/trying-to-understand-cmtime-and-cmtimemake